# Package Require HTTP Not Working

Tags: tcl

I am having issues with using "package require http". If I just have a tcl file with that line, I get the following error:

```
can't set "formMap": variable is array
while executing
"variable formMap [array get map]"
(procedure "init" line 15)
invoked from within
"init"
(in namespace eval "::http" script line 42)
invoked from within
"namespace eval http {
# Allow resourcing to not clobber existing data

variable http
if {![info exists http]} {
array set http {
    -ac..."
(file "/usr/local/naviserver4910/lib/tcl8/8.4/http-2.7.13.tm" line 16)
invoked from within
"source -encoding utf-8 /usr/local/naviserver4910/lib/tcl8/8.4/http-2.7.13.tm"
("package ifneeded http 2.7.13" script)
invoked from within
"package require http"
("uplevel" body line 2)
invoked from within
"uplevel {
package require http
```

Could someone help me with this issue? Thank you.

Edit --> After including:

```
catch {namespace delete ::http}
```

I followed package require http with:

```
http::geturl "https://google.com"
```

However, I now get the following error:

```
invalid command name "http::geturl"
while executing
"http::geturl "https://google.com""
    ("uplevel" body line 4)
    invoked from within
"uplevel {
    catch {namespace delete ::http}
package require http
http::geturl "https://google.com"
set user_id       [ad_conn user_id]

set events_o..."
    (procedure "code::tcl::/web/dev/nnab-codebook/packages/ctrl-ars/www/inde..." line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel {

        if { [file exists $__adp_stub.tcl] } {

            # ensure that data source preparation procedure exists and is up-to-date
  ..."
(procedure "adp_prepare" line 2)
invoked from within
"adp_prepare"
    invoked from within
"template::adp_parse [file rootname [ad_conn file]] {}"
    (procedure "adp_parse_ad_conn_file" line 6)
    invoked from within
"$handler"
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel $code"
    invoked from within
"ad_try {
                $handler
            } ad_script_abort val {
                # do nothing
            }"
    invoked from within
"rp_serve_concrete_file [ad_conn file]"
    (procedure "::nsf::procs::rp_serve_abstract_file" line 60)
    invoked from within
"rp_serve_abstract_file "$root/$extra_url""
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel $code"
    invoked from within
"ad_try {
                rp_serve_abstract_file "$root/$extra_url"
                set tcl_url2file([ad_conn url]) [ad_conn file]
                set ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you/NaviServer are somehow reloading the http package in an interpreter that already has a *different* version of it loaded. That's pretty strange.

What's significantly odder is that the youngest version of the http library that worked that way dates from 2004; it was changed in http 2.5.0 which was advanced to that version at the very beginning of 2005. (Apparently I did it, but I really don't remember that.) The change was applied to Tcl 8.4 and 8.5 releases (and also 8.6 and later) so I'm pretty sure that the ancient version that you're using really isn't worth using. And that's the *upper* bound for the versions that are old enough to trigger the behaviour you're seeing; they could be older than that.

All in all, it's decidedly odd. You're not really supposed to load different versions of a package into a single Tcl interpreter. That's not a particularly well-supported usage pattern (mostly because most packages don't unload their state nicely as it is hard to do well).

---

A workaround is to do this *before* the `package require`:

```
catch {namespace delete ::http}
```

Comment: Hello Donal, thank you for replying. I have included the changes on my code, but I am still having errors. I have included the error message on the top of the post. Thank you.